# Algorithm or Python function to find the q-relaxed intersection set?

Tags: python-3.x, set-theory

I am looking for a "faster" way to find the [q-relaxed intersection set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxed_intersection) of a list of sets. I have currently implemented the following Python function but it is quite slow. I would like this to work for ~100 sets and q=10. Any clever ideas?

```
def relaxed_intersection(*sets, q=0):
    """
    This function finds the q-relaxed intersection set of the sets supplied in
    *sets as a list.
    We first find the intersection of subsets formed by leaving q sets out and
    then find the union of these intersetions.
    """
    import itertools
    n = len(sets)
    #form subsets leaving q sets out
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(sets, n-q))

    #find the intersection of all the subsets
    intersections = [set() for i in range(len(combinations))]
    for i, comb in enumerate(combinations):
        intersections[i] = set.intersection(*comb)

    #find the union of all the intersections
    q_relaxed_set = set.union(*intersections)

    return q_relaxed_set
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check for each element whether they are part of at least `n - q` sets.

```
from collections import Counter

def relaxed_intersection(*sets, q=0):
    """
    This function finds the q-relaxed intersection set of the sets supplied in
    *sets as a list.
    """

    counter = Counter(x for s in sets for x in set(s))
    n = len(sets)
    return {x for x, c in counter.items() if c >= n - q}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much faster and simpler than using itertools.